# How to cache frequently used data in mongodb while using along with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, caching, node-modules

I'm using node js along with mongo db. I need help for something related to caching. I have certain data like trending posts which will be updated for every 15 mins. But for a given instance of time period all the users making the api call for the trending posts data will get same response. Hence is there any way to save the cache data from db and update it periodically for 15 mins.

Note: I doubt if storing the data in json format in a file in server will be helpful? Is it prone to attacks or malicious usages? This data contains some confidential information too. So I guess that is not a good idea to store it in files. So is there anyother methods???

Comment: I think it's better to use `Redis`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Kedar, this is where you would use some type of distributed cache like Redis.

There are NPM modules like mongodb-redis-cache

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-redis-cache)

They syntax is quite simple, just append it onto the select. (it does require a redis server though, if you are not familiar with Redis or setting one up, I would look at a more managed solution then like on Digital ocean etc )

The idea here is that each call to Mongo will first check if there is a 'cached' key/value in redis, if not it runs the query, otherwise it will just pull from Redis.

Comment: i have an idea of using redis for caching. Should i create a redis database for that? and if i need to do so, what protocol should i use to create redis or memcached?

Comment: You can host your own redis server by simply installing it on a server and opening it up to be connected to OR use managed services to do this (digital ocean has a managed instance as well as many others, might make it simpler ) Once you have that you simply use the redis npm and connect to it using the syntax, then for caching you can use something like 'apicache' module as middleware in the request. It will take care of inserting and expiring etc